# Point to Polygon toolbox crash

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing-framework

Using ArcGIS Basic 10.1, there is a symbol of a paper scroll next to the tool, instead of the hammer symbol.  That is the only tool I click on that crashes my program.

I am not sure what that paper scroll symbol means next to it.  Is there an update needed somewhere?  How else can I do the Point to Polygon conversion that I do need (without using scripting).

[image]

Comment: Does it crash when you try to initially start it, or does it crash after you have entered the parameters and try to execute it?

Comment: Where did you find the Point to Polygon tool?

Comment: I found it in the Data Management and when I click on the Point to Line.

Comment: The paper scroll simply means that the tool is a script tool.  You can open the Python script by right clicking on the scroll and by selecting "edit".  The script should pop up in notepad.  Also try running the tool directly in ArcGIS for Desktop by doubling clicking the tool rather than in ArcCatalog (as I see from your screenshot).

Comment: Aaron, I did that initially, same result.  I will try the python script as I'm not very good at the scripting portion.

Comment: Try double-clicking on the Multiple Ring Buffer (Analysis) script tool in the Analysis toolbox.  If you are receiving an error on that tool also, I suspect there is an issue with your Python directory.

Comment: Like the first question said, when are you getting the error.  Are you getting it when you open the tool, when you try filling out the parameters, or when you try running it.  If you are getting the error when you try running it, try running it with a completely different dataset (ideally a different type of data - feature class instead of shapefile or such as that).  Please let us know these so we can help you getter.

Comment: I double clicked the Multiple Ring Buffer and the program crashed. 

My end result was I used Global Mapper to convert from point to line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the selected tools as mentioned above crashing the program with each attempt, I converted the point to line using Global Mapper conversion.  The only problem with GM was it did not transfer all the data with that conversion, but that is fixable.